# My last of column of gridlayout going out of screen

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, layout, android-gridlayout

I created gridlayout of 3 columns and it's doing great with large screen phone but with small screen phone there is problem last column going out of screen.
I also tried to set column_weight="1" but it's even worse.

Please help me I stuck here for many of days and tried so many things but it  doesn't help.

```
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="8">


        <TextView
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sub"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/credit"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/grade"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/m2"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/dsa"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/dsalab"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/vee"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/eeb"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/dms"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/anel"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: show the code and snapshot please

Comment: I updated my post.please try to solve my problem @HasnainSabir

Comment: Please answer something I really need your help @HasnainSabir